Why is this damaged mirror not moving, possible ways to repair?
Honda civic coupe vti 1999.
As you can see in the pics this wing mirror is broken.  It seems to me it cracked from two parts of the plastic which I have roughly pointed out with the red arrows.
I have a few questions.

Even before this broke, if I recall correctly the mirror wasn’t turning to in or out but the other side does.  I tried to move it with my hands to see if it turns in and out but i can’t get it to.  Like I say this was the case before the mirror got broken but the other side does and should move.  With regards to the no manoeuvring, what is causing it not to move and how can I repair it?

If I manage to fix the manoeuvring issue, and then super glue the broken plastic, I will then have to manouvre the casing but will it just break as super glue will not stand up to the pressure of the constant turns at the broken areas of plastic in which case, is there another option, or will I have to buy a new wing/casing?

As you can see in the third pic, I clipped the broken casing together pushed it into place, it’s seems a bit out of place but liveable.  If I am willing to forego moving the mirror in and out, I could just super glue the mirror where it joins to the car etc in the out position.
Would you advise doing this as a permenant fix or until I get a replacement?


Thanks.




So the mirror HOUSING is what wasn’t folding and is now broken. I can’t seen from these pictures what caused that, but I’m betting it had something to do with it eventually breaking overall. Neither of those breaks look fresh, but the break on the left of your arrowed picture (more inboard towards the center of the car) looks older, based on the amount of dirt and less sharp points.
For the fix, you go to the junkyard and get another one, or you order a whole new one. You can try taping it in place, but wind will still move it as you drive. That will make the actual mirror it holds that you use to prevent wrecks unstable. For that reason, I’d definitely not consider tape a permanent fix, and I’d be extra careful driving until I fixed it. Your mind will forget at the worst time that the mirror may not be at the adjustment it’s used to seeing, and boom. Then you’re needing even more parts from the junkyard.
